# Notice: String offset cast occurred in php function

Tags: php, string

Using this to obfuscate emails and I'm getting Notice: String offset cast occurred in hide_email() (line 11 of ....)

```
function hide_email($email)
{
    $character_set = '+-.0123456789@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    $key = str_shuffle($character_set);
    $cipher_text = '';
    $id = 'e' . rand(1, 999999999);
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($email); $i += 1) {
        $cipher_text .= $key[strpos($character_set, $email[$i])];
    }
    $script = 'var a="' . $key . '";var b=a.split("").sort().join("");var c="' . $cipher_text . '";var d="";';
    $script .= 'for(var e=0;e<c.length;e++)d+=b.charAt(a.indexOf(c.charAt(e)));';
    $script .= 'document.getElementById("' . $id . '").innerHTML="<a href=\\"mailto:"+d+"\\">"+d+"</a>"';
    $script = "eval(\"" . str_replace(array("\\", '"'), array("\\\\", '\"'), $script) . "\")";
    $script = '<script type="text/javascript">/*<![CDATA[*/' . $script . '/*]]>*/</script>';
    return '<span id="' . $id . '">[javascript protected email address]</span>' . $script;
}
```

line 11 is `$cipher_text.= $key[strpos($character_set,$email[$i])];`.

Any idea how to fix that?
Thank you.

Comment: I just ran this function locally and did not receive any error. Does the email you are passing the function contain any whitespace/newline characters? I suggest doing a `trim()` on `$email` before doing anything with it.

Comment: `$email[$i]` seems to be `$email`

Comment: No white space, no funky character, no + no... the function is implemented on 4 installations of the same CMS, and I get the notice only in one of them. I have little faith in that CMS. Still. And it works.

Comment: $email[$i] loops through each character of $email. So no, I don't think it is the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
$key[INSIDE THIS MUST BE AN INTEGER - FLOAT / BOOL NOT GOOD]
```

you can check type using `var_dump()`

```
echo "dsaad"[3];
echo "dsaad"[false]; // Warning: String offset cast occurred 
echo "dsaad"[3.0];   // Warning: String offset cast occurred
```

Answer (score 0):

- [strpos](https://www.php.net/strpos) will return a boolean `false` if the "needle" is not found in the "haystack"
- `$array[$key]` will give a Warning if `$key` is a boolean value

So, if `$email[$i]` is any character not contained in `$character_set`, you will get the warning shown.

You could detect any such character, and raise an error, e.g.

```
$index = strpos($character_set, $email[$i]);
if ( $index === false ) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Invalid e-mail address supplied: $email");
}
$cipher_text .= $key[$index];
```

Or maybe rather than throwing an error, you want to leave those characters un-hidden - in that case, you'll need to make a similar check in the JS code too.